# Is it legal for my company to force me to use my personal computer for work?

Tags: software-industry, united-states, developer, software

I'm a software engineer with 4 years of experience.  I landed a job while in college as a junior dev for the same company I'm with now (3 years total at this current company) making 39k.  I now make 45k.  I know, it's terrible.

Anyways, they were supposed to supply me with a work computer at the beginning.  I had to use my own computer for the first like 12 months.  I finally talk to my manager about it almost a year later, and he tells me to pick a computer out and send him a link.  So I did.  Well, I don't hear anything for a while.  I come to my manager again and ask, this time he tells me that the higher ups decided that he needed a new computer, and that I could just get his old one.  And let me tell you something.  This computer is 6 years old Macbook, can barely run our main program (let alone build it), and many of the keys don't even function.  The best part is that the battery is fried, so it has to be connected to power 24/7 or it will just die instantly basically.

Fast forward a month later, they hire a new employee.  He does not code and mostly works sales (spreadsheets).  They bought him a brand new $2,000 Macbook. THEN, Not even a month ago, they hired someone else and they also received a brand new computer (they do not do anything computer intensive either).  And yet, here I am being expected to get stuff done with a computer that can barely search Google.

I'm already searching for a new job, but this just can't be legal, can it?  I'm thinking its because of my age.  I'm 23, and I've just always felt like they look at me like a child.  What can I do?

EDIT: I'm in the US. For those of you who clearly didn't read the entire post, I am not concerned with the salary in terms of legality.  I am discussing the legality of treating me differently from all other employees.  No need to get snarky.

EDIT 2: Thanks to all that gave good advice.  Guess I need to learn to stick up for myself.

Comment: Why do you believe, providing you used hardware, is illegal? If you cannot perform your job, with the hardware you have, you should let your manager know that is the case.

Comment: If you want to know if something is legal, we need to know where in the world you are. I am sure there are differences in labor law between lets say Belgium and North Korea.

Comment: Maybe because they have provided every single employee EXCEPT me with a brand new one, and that is pretty blatant discrimination?

Comment: The bigger legal question is the work you have been doing on your own computer as an employee.  That is legal but can bring many complications with depending on your jurisdiction

Comment: Different employees get treated differently all the time.  It only matters if the basis for the different treatment is some protected class.  You haven't provided any info that would lead us that we.  Poor management is not illegal.

Comment: This may be as simple as their having had a spare machine when you hired on but needing to buy hardware when the others hired on. Ask your manager when you're due for a hardware upgrade on the usual schedule (for us it used to be when a machine was at least four years old), or give them a good reason to believe that the older machine is hampering your productivity (and not because you're grumpy after comparing)

Comment: @EugineFrancis - It's only illegal discrimination if the reason they did not provide you new hardware, because you are a protected class, the fact you might be a protected class might have nothing to do with you not receiving new hardware.  Employees are supported by different budgets within the same company all the time. You are a software engineer, these other employees are not software engineers, which means those employees are likely part of a different team.  BLUF: **Discrimination can legal in some cases**

Comment: What the other guys have is irrelevant. Simply tell management your machine is failing and needs repair or replacement before it dies completely. Entitlement and attitude won't get you what you need; a business case should.

Comment: To be clear, they're not forcing you to use your personal computer. You're choosing to use it because the equipment they provided is insufficient for your work. You could choose to stop using your personal computer and see what they do about it.

Answer (score 10):

Is this legal? Yes.
Is it scummy? Yes.
Does it often happen that Sales get all the flashy stuff and the back-end team get left with the scraps? Yes.

I've seen this happen at many organizations. It's annoying, it sucks - but it's completely legal.

Your options are:

1: Make a business case as to why you need new hardware.
2: find out if someone with newer hardware is leaving and call dibs on their stuff.
3: Look for another job.

Answer (score 5):

Legal?  Yes.

Ethical?  No.

Your first mistake was ever agreeing to use your personal computer as your primary work computer.  They took advantage of you because you're young and eager to get yourself into adult life.

I wonder what would happen if you got into the habit of backing up your work either on a network drive or in source control for a few months, and then at some time your personal computer was *mysteriously stolen* while you were out at your favorite coffee shop.  There'd be nothing against the law, and no way for your company to force any expenses on you if your personal equipment just *came up missing* one day.  Do you think they'd spend some money on a computer, *if that were to happen to you* a few weeks later?  Friend, you're going to have to be shrewd, because some of these employers will run you into the ground.

Comment: They take advantage of him fully imo. That salary is super low. I mean if he learned anything in those 3 years, he's easily worth double what they're paying him.

Answer (score 1):

This could be 100% legal **unless** there is something in your employment contract that specifies that your salary must be higher, and your company must provide you with a brand new computer.

This situation may look like the company intentionally treats you unfairly. But, in reality, it may have a lot to do with the business side rather than discriminating against you because you are young (only 23 years old). **I don't believe this is** "**age discrimination**".

---

Sometimes, in a company, the sales department gets more cash or financial resources from the CEO than the engineering department because the CEO wants to grow the sales department more at this time in order to attract more new clients or bring in more profits from the new markets.

So, the new employees in the sales department may get that new computers while the software engineers won't get any new laptops.

---

In the same department, sometimes, rockstar employees are certainly treated differently from non-rockstar ones.

For example, in the sales department, if one new employee brings in tons of new clients or cash, then he/she would be treated highly and will get a new computer compared to the current employees who are less effective.

---

The bottom line is this:  "**It is just business. Nothing personal.**"

Most importantly, I think you should search for a new job because your salary is way too low for an engineer with 4 years of experience (**regardless of what computers they give you at work**).

Even if a company had given me 2,000 new super quantum computers to work with and only paid me 45K per year right out of college, I would have said "**No, Thanks**" right away, and look for a new job. But, it's just me (and I could be wrong). Other people may have different perspectives, preferences, or whatever, man. Just follow your dream.

Answer (score 1):

The hierarchy doesn't seem to think much of you or the importance of your work.

One avenue others haven't touched in answers is to talk to your IT support team. Their recommendations usually hold weight, and they'll understand your needs better when they do an assessment. If you don't have IT support or you are the IT support then you're better off leaving for where you're more valued.

Although if you are the IT support it's common in some places to expect you to fudge up your own computer rather than issue you a new one. Specs too low? Stick some more RAM in or a CPU from a faulty machine, or a whole board. I'm IT support, I started with an i3 4GB RAM, and although the case is the same, I'm running an i7 with 32GB RAM scavenged from all over the place. The case is the only original part.